# Can't open world.qgs as in Training Manual 6.1.1

Tags: qgis-3, qgs

I’m working through the training manual located at https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/index.html. I have QGIS 3.16 running on OS 10.15.7 (Catalina). The following describes my problem:

6. Module: Vector Analysis 6. 1.1 Follow Along: Projections.

The instructions say to save the current map and then open a map of the world under exercise_data/world/world.qgs.  I opened a new project. Then I selected Open Data Source Manager and, Since Module 6 pertains to Vector Analysis, I selected Vector on the left toolbar, and then navigated to the world.qgs file. A red banner appeared with the message that this was not a valid data file. I tried opening it without opening a new project with the same result. I then opened the previous project and tried open the file in that project. I also tried opening the file as raster data and as mesh data. The result was the same. I would like to know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: The answers were excellent. Mightn't the tags be a little more specific?

Comment: @Ben W. Done. I did not know the use of the icon. I like the tags now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file 'world.qgs' is not a vector data source- it's a project file. If you already have QGIS open the easiest way to open a project file is to simply drag and drop it onto the canvas or layers panel either from a folder in your file system, or from the browser panel within QGIS. See the gifs below for examples:

At QGIS start from a file folder:

[image]

From an already open project with the browser panel:

[image]

You can also open a project by going to the Project menu then 'Open':

[image]

Or via the Open Project action on the Project toolbar (keyboard shortcut Ctrl+O).

[image]

Comment: @user2856 and Ben W, thanks. So simple, so basic. Mightn't the tags be a little more specific? I don't have tag-creation privileges.

Comment: On rereading,  I see this was actually answered by @Ben W with excellent graphics and user2856 added options, and my tag-creation comment should have been directed at the editor. I will copy it there.